# Diccionarios de python y bool

Tags: python, diccionarios, booleano

debo hacer un código donde me permita invitar a una persona a ver una película y, dependiendo su edad, haga distintas cosas.
Los requisitos son:
Cuando tú quieras invitar a un familiar o a un amigo a ver una película dada, es indispensable que tu programa verifique el cumplimiento de ciertas restricciones, en especial cuando el invitado es un menor de edad:

Tú puedes invitar a cualquier persona a ver cualquier película, si la persona es mayor de edad

NO se puede invitar personas menores de 15 años a ver películas de género Terror

Si el invitado tiene 10 años o menos, solo se puede invitar a ver películas de género Familiar.

Si la edad del invitado no cumple con la clasificación por edad de la película, el invitado debe contar con la autorización de los padres para verla, excepto si la película es de género Documental

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
def decidir_invitar(peli: dict, edad_invitado: int, autorizacion_padres: bool)->bool:
    """
    Parametros:
        peli (dict): Pelicula que se desea ver con el invitado
        edad_invitado (int): Edad del invitado con quien se desea ver la pelicula
        autorizacion_padres (bool): Indica si el invitado cuenta con la autorizacion de sus padres 
        para ver la pelicula
    Retorna:
        bool: True en caso de que se pueda invitar a la persona, False de lo contrario.
    """
    se_puede = False
    if edad_invitado >= 18:
        se_puede = True
    elif edad_invitado < 18:
        if edad_invitado < 15:
            if peli['genero'] == 'Terror':
                se_puede = False
            else:
                se_puede = True
        elif edad_invitado < 10:
            if peli['genero'] == 'Familiar':
                se_puede = True
            else:
                se_puede = False
        elif edad_invitado < int(peli['clasificacion']):
            if autorizacion_padres:
                se_puede = True
            else:
                se_puede = False
    return se_puede
```

El error es que cuando pongo que es mayor a 18, me sigue preguntando el permiso de los padres. Además, en la parte de edad_invitado < int(peli['clasificacion'], me da error ya que no toma el valor de la clasificación correctamente.
Las películas del ejemplo son:

```
def crear_pelicula(nombre: str, genero: str, duracion: int, anio: int, 
                  clasificacion: str, hora: int, dia: str) -> dict:
    """Crea un diccionario que representa una nueva película con toda su información inicializada.
    Parámetros:
        nombre (str): Nombre de la pelicula agendada.
        genero (str): Generos de la pelicula separados por comas.
        duracion (int): Duracion en minutos de la pelicula
        anio (int): Anio de estreno de la pelicula
        clasificacion (str): Clasificacion de restriccion por edad
        hora (int): Hora a la cual se planea ver la pelicula, esta debe estar entre 
                    0 y 2359
        dia (str): Dia de la semana en el cual se planea ver la pelicula.
    Retorna:
        dict: Diccionario con los datos de la pelicula
    """ 
    diccionario = {'nombre':nombre, 'genero':genero, 'duracion':duracion, 'anio':anio,
                   'clasificacion':clasificacion, 'hora':hora, 'dia':dia
        }
    return diccionario

pelicula1 = mod.crear_pelicula("Shrek",  "Familiar, Comedia", 92, 2001, 'Todos', 1700, "Viernes")
    pelicula2 = mod.crear_pelicula("Get Out",  "Suspenso, Terror", 104, 2017, '18+', 2330, "Sábado")  
    pelicula3 = mod.crear_pelicula("Icarus",  "Documental, Suspenso", 122, 2017, '18+', 800, "Domingo")
    pelicula4 = mod.crear_pelicula("Inception",  "Acción, Drama", 148, 2010, '13+', 1300, "Lunes")
    pelicula5 = mod.crear_pelicula("The Empire Strikes Back",  "Familiar, Ciencia-Ficción", 124, 1980, '7+', 1415, "Miércoles") 

def ejecutar_decidir_invitar(p1: dict, p2: dict, p3: dict, p4: dict, p5: dict)->None:
    """Ejecuta la opcion de decidir si se puede invitar a alguien a ver una pelicula o no.
    Parametros:
        p1 (dict): Diccionario que contiene la informacion de la pelicula 1.
        p2 (dict): Diccionario que contiene la informacion de la pelicula 2.
        p3 (dict): Diccionario que contiene la informacion de la pelicula 3.
        p4 (dict): Diccionario que contiene la informacion de la pelicula 4.
        p5 (dict): Diccionario que contiene la informacion de la pelicula 5.
    """
    print("Decidir si se puede invitar a alguien a ver una pelicula")

    nom_peli = input("Ingrese el nombre de la pelicula: ")
    pelicula = mod.encontrar_pelicula(nom_peli,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)

    if pelicula is None:
        print("No hay ninguna pelicula con este nombre")
    else:
        edad_invitado = int(input("Ingrese la edad del invitado: "))
        autorizacion_padres = bool(input("Si los padres autorizan al invitado, digite 1. En caso contrario, digite 0: "))
    retornar = mod.decidir_invitar(nom_peli, edad_invitado, autorizacion_padres)
    print(retornar)
```

Mi intento es el siguiente:

Decidir si se puede invitar a alguien a ver una pelicula
Ingrese el nombre de la pelicula: Icarus

Ingrese la edad del invitado: 15

Si los padres autorizan al invitado, digite 1. En caso contrario, digite 0: 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Palu y facu\OneDrive\Escritorio\Python spyder\Programacion en Python\consola_peliculas.py", line 245, in 
iniciar_aplicacion()

File "C:\Users\Palu y facu\OneDrive\Escritorio\Python spyder\Programacion en Python\consola_peliculas.py", line 193, in iniciar_aplicacion
ejecutando = mostrar_menu_aplicacion(pelicula1, pelicula2, pelicula3, pelicula4, pelicula5)

File "C:\Users\Palu y facu\OneDrive\Escritorio\Python spyder\Programacion en Python\consola_peliculas.py", line 236, in mostrar_menu_aplicacion
ejecutar_decidir_invitar(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)

File "C:\Users\Palu y facu\OneDrive\Escritorio\Python spyder\Programacion en Python\consola_peliculas.py", line 154, in ejecutar_decidir_invitar
retornar = mod.decidir_invitar(nom_peli, edad_invitado, autorizacion_padres)

File "C:\Users\Palu y facu\OneDrive\Escritorio\Python spyder\Programacion en Python\modulo_peliculas.py", line 311, in decidir_invitar
elif edad_invitado < int(peli['clasificacion']):
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Te da algún error al ejecutar o no sale lo que esperabas? En el segundo caso ¿qué probaste, qué esperabas y qué salió? Como programador es tan importante (o más) que aprendas a programar como que aprendas a reportar correctamente los problemas.

Comment: Lo siento. El error es que cuando pongo que es mayor a 18, me sigue preguntando el permiso de los padres. Además, en la parte de edad_invitado < int(peli['clasificacion'], me da error ya que no toma el valor de la clasificación correctamente

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir esta información para que sea más visible, en lugar de dejarla en un comentario

Comment: Gracias. Todavía soy nuevo en la página y este problema está liquidando mis neuronas

Comment: Las películas de ejemplo que has añadido no son diccionarios, es una tupla. ¿Estás seguro de que te vienen así? Por otro lado, la parte en que miras si la edad es mayor de 18 está correcta. Si te falla tendrá que ser por otra razón. Muestra el código desde el cual llamas a la función para ver cómo le pasas los parámetros.

Comment: Copié y pegué el código y utilicé la función que escribiste, funciona de forma correcta, para los mayores de 18 el resultado siempre es True. Tal vez sea mejor que pongas también la forma en que estas usando la función para reproducir el error que tienes

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu problema no es reproducible, por favor mira [mcve] y agrega un ejemplo que reproduzca tu error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varias cosas no están bien en el algoritmo de este código. Uno de los errores que muestras es porque estás comparando la edad int del invitado con otra cosa que no es un numero `elif edad_invitado < int(peli['clasificacion']):` por ejemplo `13 < int('16+')`, obvio que eso va a dar error.

Por otro lado, tienes `p1, p2, ... p5`. ¿Y si son 1000 películas? Precisamente esa es lo que se busca evitar con las estructuras de datos (listas, diccionarios, etc)

Cuando se hace un desarrollo, no se debe hacer trabajar de más a la persona que va a usar esa interface. Por ejemplo, ¿Por qué preguntarle la edad a alguien que va a ver **Shrek** si es para Todo Público? o ¿Por qué preguntarle autorización de los padres a una persona de 17 que va a ver una película de 13+?

Viendo todas esas cosas yo escribiría 2 funciones así:

```
peliculas = {} # Variable global, Aqui se guardarán todas las peliculas

def crear_pelicula(p=False):
    if p == False:
        nombre = input("Nombre de la pelicula: ")
        if nombre in peliculas:
            print("Ya esa pelicula existe, vuelva a intentarlo");
            return
        genero = input("Genero: ")
        durac = input("Duración: ")
        anio = input("Año: ")
        clasif = input("Clasificación: ")
        hora = input("Hora: ")
        dia = input("Dia: ")
        p = [nombre, genero, durac, anio, clasif, hora, dia]
    elif (type(p) != list) or (len(p) != 7):
        print("Los datos no son correctos, no se agregó la pelicula")
        return
    # ###
    peliculas[p[0]] = {'genero':p[1], 'duracion':int(p[2]), 'anio':int(p[3]), 
    'clasificacion':p[4], 'hora':p[5], 'dia':p[6]}
    print("Pelicula agregada ->", p[0])
    
def verificar_permiso(p):
    if p['clasificacion'] == 'Todos':
        return True
    se_puede = True
    generos = p['genero'].replace(' ', '').split(',')
    edad = int(input("Ingrese la edad del invitado: "))
    if edad < 15 and 'Terror' in generos:
        se_puede = False
    elif edad < 10 and 'Familiar' not in generos:
        se_puede = False
    elif edad <= int(p['clasificacion'][:-1]):
        print("AVERTENCIA: Esta pelicula tiene clasificacion de edad")
        autorizacion = input("Si los padres autorizan al invitado digite 1, en caso contrario 0: ")
        if not int(autorizacion):
            se_puede = False
    return se_puede
```

Las películas se guardarán en una variable global `peliculas`, la cual se puede acceder tanto fuera como dentro de las funciones. Se que no es buena práctica usar variables globales, pero como esto generalmente debe estar en una base de datos, es un buen pretexto para trabajarlo en una variable de este tipo. De todas formas: NO TE ACOSTUMBRES A USARLAS para cualquier cosa.

La función `crear_pelicula()` acepta valores automáticos enviándole una lista de 7 elementos con los datos, o también de forma manual `p = false`.
Entonces se le puede añadir películas al diccionario global para crear la base de datos inicial:

```
# ### Llenar algunos datos automáticos
crear_pelicula(["Shrek", "Familiar, Comedia", 92, 2001, 'Todos', 1700, "Viernes"])
crear_pelicula(["Get Out", "Suspenso, Terror", 104, 2017, '18+', 2330, "Sábado"])  
crear_pelicula(["Icarus", "Documental, Suspenso", 122, 2017, '18+', 800, "Domingo"])
crear_pelicula(["Inception", "Acción, Drama", 148, 2010, '13+', 1300, "Lunes"])
crear_pelicula(["The Empire Strikes Back",  "Familiar, Ciencia-Ficción", 124, 1980, '7+', 1415, "Miércoles"])
```

Finalmente el programa principal quedará de la siguiente manera. Si juntas los 3 bloques el programa quedará funcional.

```
while(True):
    print()
    print("1- Invitar a alguien")
    print("2- Agregar otra pelicula")
    print("x- Salir")
    op = input("Seleccione una opción: ")
    if op == '1':
        pelicula = input("Ingrese el nombre de la película: ")
        if pelicula not in peliculas:
            print("Esa película no existe")
            continue
        p = peliculas[pelicula]
        # ###
        if verificar_permiso(p):
            print("Puede mirar la pelicula")
        else:
            print("Lo sentimos, no está autorizado a ver esta película")
    elif op == '2':
        crear_pelicula()
    else:
        break;
```

Comment: El código que pasé corresponde a un programa mayor que, por cuestiones de ética, no puedo publicar completo (es un trabajo práctico y el único problema que tenía era este)